# Can you bring breakfast cereal into the UK?

Tags: uk, prohibited-items

Can you bring breakfast cereal for children with you to the UK from a Non EU country?

1 sealed pack (500 grams) in its original commercial packing, as bought from the store. Nestle / Heinz if it matters. Cereals for Children do contain fruits traces if that matters.

If it is allowed, do you need to Declare it on arrival?

I have looked at [GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/bringing-food-products-into-the-uk) but I am unable to come to a definite yes/no

I know that you can instantly get cereal from any shop in the UK but If we can avoid *"But this one is not my favourite"* that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem bringing breakfast cereal into the UK, from anywhere in the world, as can be seen from the UK Government Guidance on [Personal Food, Plant and Animal Product Imports](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/personal-food-plant-and-animal-product-imports).

From outside the EU, meat and meat products, dairy and dairy products, and potatoes are banned. Some other things are restricted to up to 2kg or 20kg per person but the only things on those lists that could be relevant are honey and some fruits: you're not going to have 2kg (about 4lbs) of fruit or honey in your cereal.

Imports are restricted primarily to avoid introducing agricultural pests and diseases and other invasive species to the UK. Packaged breakfast cereal shouldn't have anything alive in it.

Answer (score 1):

My reading of that is that you will be okay.  To be sure, you could declare it on arrival.  I expect that the value is low so it is not a great risk if it is confiscated.

However, I would be in the camp of not taking it and buying it here.  If there is a danger of a tantrum due to the wrong breakfast cereal then you may need to worry about many other odd things here.

Where do you come from?  We may be able to warn you of other potential problem as well as breakfast cereal.

What breakfast cereal anyway?  We may be able to tell you whether it is easily available here.  To be very fair, some companies actually formulate products for different countries slightly differently.  I have actually been inside a Nestle factory making breakfast cereals and seen slightly different products going into to boxes with the same name (but different language labels).  For example, a slightly sweeter version may sell better in some countries but less well in others.  Typical temperatures may also affect the formulation.  However, if your children spot these differences then they have a very sensitive palate.  I would expect that if the box has the right name and picture on it then you will be okay.

If they have a sensitive palate then the milk may be a concern but you cannot bring in your own milk.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to declare any food items?

Comment: The question specifically asked for information about whether it was allowed to bring breakfast cereal into the UK, not for judgments about the OP's children.

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to declare commercial packaged foods in small volumes for tax or for biological security (boxed breakfast cereal is cooked so won't contain viable plant seeds or animal parasites).

Comment: I believe this is ccorrect, but a citation to back up the claims would be good.